# Relational Database Design (E-Commence) - Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectmodel

In my e-commence app (for café/restaurants) I currently have the following database structure.

[image]

The cart is the shopping cart, in which you can add products, a temporary place before the products/an order is sent to the server. The `ProductCart` is a line item, many products (could be the same) with the different quantities, sizes, frying levels etc. When a order is sent, the cart is cleared and the products in the cart is transfered to the `ProductOrder` entity (an `Order`).

I now want to extend this further, with the ability of the products having ingredients and this is where it gets tricky and too complex for my head and database skills :-). As well as the (same) products can have different sizes and frying levels (hence the line item) a product should have the ability to have many different ingredients (add ons) for example a pizza, where you could choose the topping. This is what I have tried so far:

[image]

But I am not sure if this is the right structure or way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion.

Remove `ProductOrder` and `Order` entities. They are the same as `ProductCart` and `Cart`.

Now `ProductCart` should have an attribute like `synchronized` that is `1` or `0` based if it has been sent to server or not.

Through this you should simplify a lot your model. About `Ingredient…` entities they seem ok to me.

Comment: I'll reload the page before submitting next time ;-)

Comment: @DanShelly Not a problem. You could leave your reply. It's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is something fundamental you have not grasped about Core Data. Your `ProductOrder` entity is essentially a join table. This is completely unnecessary if you are not tracking additional attributes in this table.

Instead, you should have a many-to-many relationship between `Order` and `Product`.

It might seem that `ProductCart` satisfies my condition above that in this case a join table makes sense. But no - you should simply add the orders to your cart and track all the information in the `Order` entity.

Comment: I agree with your answer but in this case those entities are not useful since can be collapsed by means of a boolean value. Anyway it's my personal advice.

Comment: My answer could include your or any other boolean value if that is deemed necessary or convenient.